# Rule T in First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

In Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (second edition, page 118), we are given the so-called *Rule T* (Lemma $24C$) :

> If $\Gamma\vdash\alpha_1,\ldots,\Gamma\vdash\alpha_n$ and $\left\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\right\}$ tautologically implies $\beta$, then $\Gamma\vdash\beta$.

Conceptually, this is fine. However, I don't quite see how/why it is used in the following example:

> Show that $\vdash\forall x\forall y(x=y\to y=x)$:
>
> 1. $\vdash x=y\to (x=x\to y=x)\qquad\text{(Axiom 6)}$
> 2. $\vdash x=x\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\text{(Axiom 5)}$
> 3. $\vdash x=y\to y=x\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\text{(Rule T)}$
> 4. $\vdash \forall y(x=y\to y=x)\qquad\qquad\quad\text{(Generalization Theorem)}$
> 5. $\vdash \forall x\forall y(x=y\to y=x)\qquad\qquad\text{(Generalization Theorem)}$

Furthermore, from the definition given above, if we already have $\Gamma\vdash\alpha_1,\ldots,\Gamma\vdash\alpha_n$ and $\Gamma\vdash\alpha_1\to\ldots\to\alpha_n\to\beta$ (since this is a tautology), then how is *Rule T* different from $n$ applications of *Modus Ponens*? Or is it precisely that?

Comment: Yes, it is precisely that; see page 118 : "PROOF. [if $\{ \alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n \}$ tautologically implies $\beta$, then] $\alpha_1 → \ldots → \alpha_n → \beta$ is a tautology, and hence a logical axiom. Apply modus ponens $n$ times."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to apply *Rule T* with $\Gamma = \emptyset$ and using the *tautological implication* :

> $A \to (B \to C) \vDash B \to (A \to C)$

where $B$ is $x=x$.

In this way, from 1, we get :

1'. $ \ \vdash x=x \to (x=y \to y=x)$

and with 2. we can derive 3. by *modus ponens*.

Comment: Why is MP (modus ponens) not explicitly mentioned by the textbook for line 3 in the example?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784668/is-this-line-in-this-proof-derived-by-lemma-24c-rule-t-alone

Comment: you haven't answered my question. why did you close my post?

Comment: @Tim - your post is a duplicate of this one: the answer above answer your question: "In this way, from 1, and with 2. we can derive 3. by modus ponens."