# Is this line in this proof derived by Lemma 24C (Rule T) alone?

Tags: logic

Enderton's An Mathematical Introduction to Logic says on p122:

> EXAMPLE. $\vdash x = y \to \forall z Pxz \to \forall z Pyz$.
>
> PROOF
>
> 1. $\vdash x = y \to Pxz \to Pyz$. Ax 6.
> 2. $\vdash z Pxz \to Pxz $. Ax 2.
> 3. $\vdash x = y \to \forall z Pxz \to Pyz $. 1, 2; T.
> 4. $ \{ x = y , \forall z Pxz \} \vdash Pyz $. 3; MP^2 .
> 5. $ \{ x = y , \forall z Pxz \} \vdash \forall z Pyz $. 4; gen.
> 6. $\vdash x = y \to \forall z Pxz \to \forall z Pyz $. 5; ded^2 .

I was wondering if line 3 is derived from line 1 and line 2 by Lemma 24C (Rule T) alone? If MP (Modus Ponens) is also used, why is it not mentioned for line 3, but for line 4?

Similar question to [the example prior to this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294321/rule-t-in-first-order-logic).

Thanks.